# Maximum number of xml nodes in document?

Tags: xml, xslt, max, nodes, apply-templates

i have the following XML Structure (for example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node attr="first">
  <node attr="n1">
    <text>..</text>
  </node>
  <node attr="m1">
    <text>..</text>
  </node>
  <node attr="m1">
    <text>..</text>
  </node>
</node>
```

In my XSL transformation i try to apply a template like `<xsl:apply-templates/>` and give the matched node with the attribute 'n1'.

```
<xsl:variable name="xmlFile" select="example-file.xml"/>
<xsl:variable name="ctrl" select="document($xmlFile)/node/node[@attr='n1']"/>

<xsl:apply-templates mode="foo" select="$ctrl">
  <xsl:with-param name="bar" select="//someNode"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

That works fine if my XML document have a maximum number of 4388 XML nodes (with attribute 'm1').
But it does not work if the number of XML nodes (with attribute 'm1') are higher than 4390 nodes.

Is there a limit of xml nodes to use apply-templates like in my example?

Comment: Extensible Markup Language (XML), as the name says, doesn't have any limits..

Comment: Thank you for comment. Then i have another Question. Is it possible that XALAN-JAVA V1 have any limits?

Comment: Could this be a memory limit?

Comment: Btw, it works if i do a template call `<xsl:call-template />`

But that is not the solution for me.

Comment: Never tell us something "doesn't work". Tell us how it fails.

Comment: My suspicion would be stack overflow. Seeing an error message would help to confirm that.

Comment: I became no notification about an error. That's why i am creating this ticket. Sorry Michael but your Books are also not helpful for this error...